# Why ref value is correct in useEffect but nullish in component body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is probably very trivial but Im looking for a proper answer:

Why is `someRef` available in `useEffect`, but its `null` in `Child` body?

How is it possible?

Especially when the component do not re-render. It looks like `useEffect` is kind of an abstract layer over component? It sounds ridiculous

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;

const Child = ({ someRef }) => {
  console.log('body', someRef);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
     console.log('hiya', someRef);
  }, [someRef]);

  console.log('body', someRef);
  return null;
}

const App = () => {
  const someRef = useRef(null);

  return (
     <div>
      <div ref={someRef}>text1</div>
      <Child someRef={someRef} />
     </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is a render order issue. It's calling `console.log('body', someRef);` before mounting and then the `useEffect` runs after mount.

Answer (score 2):

The ref doesn't get assigned to until the `App` fully renders for the first time and the HTMLElements are created. When components are first mounting in an app, any refs tied to elements will initially not be defined until the initial mount cycle is completed. That's why the `useEffect` in `Child` properly displays the ref as populated with the `<div>`.

You don't need to wait for the `someRef` to change in Child (and you shouldn't, since the ref object doesn't change anyway) - all you need to do is wait for the initial mount to complete. This would work too:

```
const Child = ({ someRef }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
     console.log('hiya', someRef);
  }, []);
```

You can think of

```
<div ref={someRef}>
```

a bit like

```
<div onThisElementInsertedIntoDOM={function() { someRef.current = this; }}
```

Not *exactly*, but you get the idea. The element hasn't been inserted yet when you log them in the function body for the first time. The elements may be in the process of being created, but they haven't made it into the DOM yet.

Comment: Hold on. So when the first `console.log` is called, the `Child` component is not mounted yet? How is it possible?

Comment: The whole `<App>` and everything it renders hasn't been inserted into the DOM at the time you log `someRef` in the `Child` function body. The ref only gets assigned to after all component main function bodies run, after mounting is complete.

Comment: So when the `console.log` is called, the `Child` is **mounted** but the whole mounting process isnt done yet, right? Also it means that `useEffect` is kinda async? And it runs only after whole mounting process has finished. Agreed?

Comment: The Child hasn't mounted at the time that its function body is running - it's not in the DOM yet. The time that refs get assigned to is similar to just before `componentDidMount`, if you're familiar with class components. Yes, the elements getting inserted into the DOM and the `useEffect` are slightly asynchronous. I think you have the general idea.

Comment: This is what I thought. Thanks for making things clear.